# how to create an android button loading a web page?

Tags: android

I am super new to android apps and I am trying to create an app that just loads a webpage when clicked.
I, however, keep getting an error that: `can't find symbol variable URL`

Here is my MainActivity code:

```
  package com.example.logger;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
        public void browser1(View view) {
            Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,url.parse("xxxxxxxxxxx"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
      }
}
```

Kindly help with figuring out what I'm missing.

Comment: that is probably because there is no such thing as `url` defined anywhere. You are likely missing Java basics.

Comment: try `Uri.parse('YOUR URL')`

Comment: I've tried that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `Uri`, not `url`

```
 Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("xxxxxxx"));
```

Make sure you have  `import android.net.Uri` on top.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add permission In Manifests file

   ```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   ```
2. Add this in xml file

   ```
   <WebView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/webview"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
   ```
3. Add this in MainActivity

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       ProgressDialog pd;
       WebView wv;
       String url="www.google .com";

       private ImageView back3;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_social_media);
           back3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back3);
           back3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   onBackPressed();
               }
           });
           wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
           pd = new ProgressDialog(SocialMedia.this);
           pd.setCancelable(true);
           pd.setMessage("Loading....");
           // pd.setIcon(R.drawable.load);
           // wv.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
           wv.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser(pd));
           wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

           wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
           wv.loadUrl(url);
       }
       public  class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient{
           ProgressDialog pd;

           public MyBrowser(ProgressDialog pd) {
               this.pd = pd;
               pd.show();
           }


           @Override
           public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
               view.loadUrl(url);
               return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
           }

           @Override
           public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
               super.onPageFinished(view, url);
               if(pd.isShowing()){
                   pd.dismiss();
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
               super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error"+description,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }

   }
   ```